# How to Know if a Stream Has Changed (something has been added)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a stream for a chat (it updates the list of messages), and I need to know if a new message has been added to the stream (or to the database) so that I can show an indicator to let the client user know that there's a message that it hasn't read yet.

Here's my Stream:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('serverTimestamp')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data['text'];
          //
          var messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            text: messageText,
          );
          //
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 5),
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior: MyBehavior(),
              child: ListView(
                reverse: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                children: messageBubbles,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Do let me know if more information is needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something was changed ,i.e, added, removed, modified

```
if (snapshot.data.documentChanges.length != 0) {
  // Some changes were made. Show Indicator
}
```

Comment: In your case what is exactly `snapshot`? Which class is it?